# Joomla external API and data access after 1.5

Tags: joomla

I am wondering by what the old XML RPC API  will be replaced ? We developed a quite complete native(iOS+Android) and HTML5 implementation for the front-end and we'd like to offer that as SDK and REST API.

Right now we are trying to avoid any additional PHP plugin/extension for Joomla and we are currently very interested how we can automate else the data flow for customers. Currently we already support SQL direct access, complete Akeeba backups, or a local/remote Jave-App which feeds the apps from SQL directly, as cron job for instance. At the end and it should go all into our JSON format.

Is there any other project which provides a sort a formal or specified access to Joomla content and functions beyond the internal PHP Joomla API ?  We just don't know what will be the replacement(it was too basic anyway). The Joomla website and the docs doesn't help at all to figure such things out.

I hope this question is legitim here. Any suggestion is welcome. thanks,
g.

Comment: Well, seems I am not alone : http://docs.joomla.org/Xml-rpc_changes_in_Joomla!_1.6